# How to solve rasa server log duplication problem?

Tags: python, logging, rasa

I'm stuck with the problem when my log messages are duplicated. In short I have rasa server that uses 2 files preprocessing.py and intents.py. Each has own logger and handler and only once each method called. But when i run rasa server logs are duplicated. Any ideas what am i doing wrong?

```
2021-01-20 08:45:23 INFO     BERT_PREPROCESS  - Loading tokenizer
2021-01-20 08:45:23.592 INFO BERT_PREPROCESS – Tokenizer loaded
2021-01-20 08:45:23 INFO     BERT_PREPROCESS  - Tokenizer loaded
2021-01-20 08:45:23.592 INFO INTENTS – Loading model
2021-01-20 08:45:23 INFO     INTENTS  - Loading model
2021-01-20 08:45:24.781 INFO INTENTS – Model loaded
2021-01-20 08:45:24 INFO     INTENTS  - Model loaded
```

UPD
In each script logger is created the same way. Only one logger defined in each script and on one handler added. And there is definetly no duplication in logging by hand.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
```

Comment: Maybe you are adding two handlers to the loggers, or all handlers to the root logger. Can't say without knowing more about the setup. How are you creating the loggers?

Comment: @blues description updated